# UnicodeDecodeError when try to read data from 'google.com' in Python

Tags: python, database, url, encoding, decoding

I'm starting to learn about reading data from a website. But when I try to read data from google.com I encounter this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 279: invalid continuation byte
```

Below are my code (extractly as the instruction video, only different website):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
fhand=urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifing the encoding and error handling should solve the problem:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
fhand=urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="backslashreplace").strip())
```

When you are learning web scraping with python you might wanna have a look at BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/